# Redshift - How to change data type of a column when inserting?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column `metric_date` of type Varchar in a Redshift table. It contains date values in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I wanted to change the type of a column to Date and made the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE main.metrics
ALTER COLUMN metric_date TYPE DATE 
USING to_date(metric_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But it resulted in the following error:

```
Invalid operation: target data type "date" is not supported;
```

I decided to create a new table where `metric_date` will have a Date type and then insert data from the old table. But how do I insert values from a column of Varchar type to the `metric_date` column of Date type in a new table?

```
CREATE TABLE main.metrics_new
(  metric_id       varchar(20),
   metric_name     varchar(20),
   metric_date     date
);

INSERT INTO main.metrics_new
( metric_id,
  metric_name,
  metric_date // Date type here
)
SELECT
metric_id,
metric_name,
metric_date // Varchar type here
FROM main.metrics;
```

Comment: Note that I have edited question & tags as redshift <> postgres

Comment: Please give an example of what the metric_date column contains

Comment: @JonScott `2018-01-25`

Comment: try metric_date::date